# Understanding Shallow in Nested Resources in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I need to do nested resources for 3 models:

- Families (Dog, Cat, Bird)
- Breeds (Beagle, Boxer...)
- Animals

Following Rails Guides recommendations I shouldn't do this:

```
  resources :families
    resources :breeds
      resources :animals
    end
  end
```

and "[Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)" recommend to use "shallow" instead, so I should do this:

```
  resources :families, shallow: true do
    resources :breeds, shallow: true do
      resources :animals
    end
  end
```

I understand what "Guides" says "not nest the member actions"... only: [:index, :new, :create] ...

**But** it seems to work only for the 2 last nested resources, with 3 nested resources (like my case) `rake routes` give me:

```
Prefix:            breed_animals
Verb:              GET
URI Pattern:       /breeds/:breed_id/animals(.:format)
Controller#Action: animals#index
```

And I expected in URI Pattern:

```
URI Pattern:    /family/:family_id/breeds/:breed_id/animals(.:format)
```

¿What do I'm losing?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is expected when using shallow routing:

`/breeds/:breed_id`

This is shallow as breed ID will be unique no matter which family you are in.

Therefore the index of animals for that breed will also be correct for that route and shallow routing is behaving as expected.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, doesn't matter the Family if I have Breed, ok.

Comment: But: Is my code correct?: resources :families, shallow: true do
    resources :breeds, shallow: true do
      resources :animals
    end
  end

Comment: Well, I have found out the answer: The second `, shallow: true do` ,is not necessary, thanks